# Disabling default styling for button:disabled

Tags: css

Is there any way to revert the default styling of button:disabled WIHTOUT using all: unset? I don't know what is being changed because if I do something like this:

```
button:disabled {
opacity: 1;
}
```

it still dosent work

Comment: Why can't you use `all: unset` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the `background-color` instead of `opacity`

```css
button:disabled {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button disabled>Button Disabled</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: This worked! For some reason I thought it was the opacity and and note the color itself

Comment: Is not problem, that is why we all are here to help each other.